# Datasets from object to create chart

Tags: jquery, charts

Via an api call I have an object that I'm trying to use to create a chart with [CHART.XKCD](https://timqian.com/chart.xkcd/#getting_started).

Creating a bar chart works as I have just one key However I can't figure out how to get to a stacked bar chart where there are multiple keys.

Can someone tell me how to achieve this?

```js
const result  = {
  'title': 'What a show',
  'xlabel': 'Month',
  'data': {
    'labels': [
      '01',
      '02',
      '04'
    ],
    'datasets': {
      'PinTotalMonth': [
        0,
        0,
        272
      ],
      'BankTotalMonth': [
        2195,
        930,
        '786.5'
      ],
      'ContantTotalMonth': [
        0,
        0,
        '264.25'
      ]
    }
  },
  'ylabel': 'Count'
};


var ylabel = result.ylabel;
var xlabel = result.xlabel;
var labels = result.data.labels;
var mydata = result.data.datasets;
var label = "Data";

$.each(result.data.datasets, function(key, value) {
  console.log("Data: " + "type: " + key + " en value: " + value);
  // alert(key + ': ' + value);
});

const svgStackedBar = document.querySelector('.stacked-bar-chart');
new chartXkcd.StackedBar(svgStackedBar, {
  ylabel: ylabel,
  xlabel: xlabel,
  data: {
    labels: labels,
    datasets: [{
      label: label,
      data: mydata
    }]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.xkcd@1.1.12/dist/chart.xkcd.min.js"></script>

<svg class="stacked-bar-chart"></svg>
```

Comment: I am still trying to massage your data into something that would not give error. That is actually your task here.

Comment: Staring so long at this problem I didn't see this error in the data structure. It'll be some work to get this solved at the server. Anyhow many thanks for pointing me the error.

Comment: I like the charts - they do look like XKCD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were MANY issues.

One of the issues was the weird strings in the data instead of floats.

I mapped the datasets to fit the [documentation](https://timqian.com/chart.xkcd/)

```js
const result = {
  'title': 'What a show',
  'xlabel': 'Month',
  'data': {
    'labels': [
      '01',
      '02',
      '04'
    ],
    'datasets': {
      'PinTotalMonth': [
        0,
        0,
        272
      ],
      'BankTotalMonth': [
        2195,
        930,
        786.5
      ],
      'ContantTotalMonth': [
        0,
        0,
        264.25
      ]
    }
  },
  'ylabel': 'Count'
};


var ylabel = result.ylabel;
var xlabel = result.xlabel;
var labels = result.data.labels;
var mydata = result.data.datasets;
var label = "Data";

const data = {
  labels: labels,
  datasets: Object.keys(result.data.datasets).map(key => ({
    label: key,
    data: result.data.datasets[key]
  }))
}


const svgStackedBar = document.querySelector('.stacked-bar-chart');
new chartXkcd.StackedBar(svgStackedBar, {
  ylabel: ylabel,
  xlabel: xlabel,
  data: data
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.xkcd@1.1.12/dist/chart.xkcd.min.js"></script>

<svg class="stacked-bar-chart"></svg>
```

Comment: The strings in the data I need to make disappear at the server. Didn't know this would be a problem. Nice to see you got it working.